# Breakdown of the cost and time required for Fizzbuzz in worst case

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, fizzbuzz

The Fizz-Buzz function (in pseudocode) takes any positive integer *n*. I'm especially curious about the algebraic breakdown of the cost and time required of the if-else statement. I know its worst case running time is O(n).

```
Fizz-Bizz(n)
  for i = 1 to n
    if (n % 3 == 0)
      print "fizz"
    if (n % 5 == 0)
      print "buzz"
    if (n % 3 != 0 and n % 5 != 0)
      print n
```

Example of breakdown of another algorithm: [image]

Comment: Running time depends on a lot of things. Time complexity is O(n). The performance of `if` and `else` is irrelevant to the complexity so long as they’re constant-time compared to the input (which they are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity is `O(n)` because the `if` statement has no real effect on that. The complexity of the `if` statement is constant over a large enough dataset.

The `if` statement may actually do a different amount of work in iterations where you have a multiple of three or five but, the amount of extra work *per loop iteration* is not dependent on `n`. In fact, it averages out to a constant as `n` becomes bigger.

> And, as an aside, I think that code may be wrong. At multiples of fifteen, it should print both `fizz` *and* `buzz`.

If you want to do it to the level in your edit (the added breakdown), you simply need to assign an arbitrary cost `ci` to each statement (and this cost is constant for a single execution of that statement) then figure out how many times each statement is run.

For example, the first `if` sequence runs `n` times, the `print "fizz"` runs for one-third of those, `n/3`. So you end up with something like this table:

```
                           cost   times
Fizz-Buzz(n)
  for i = 1 to n           c1     n
    if (n % 3 == 0)        c2     n
      print "fizz"         c3     n / 3       [call this a]
    else
      if (n % 5 == 0)      c4     n - a
        print "buzz"       c5     (n - a) / 5 [call this b]
      else
        print n            c6     n - a - b
```

Add up all of those as per your example (substituting the `n`-equations for `a` and `b`) and, in the end, you'll *still* end up with something dependent on `n`, hence an `O(n)` algorithm. It'll look something like:

```
  c1*n + c2*n + c3*n/3   + c4*(n-a)   + c5*(n-a)/5     + c6*(n-a-b)
= c1*n + c2*n + (c3/3)*n + c4*(n-n/3) + (c5/5)*(n-n/3) + c6*(n-n/3-(n-n/3)/5)
= c1*n + c2*n + (c3/3)*n + c4*(2/3)*n + (c5/5)*(2/3)*n + c6*(n-n/3-(n-n/3)/5)
= c1*n + c2*n + (c3/3)*n + (c4*2/3)*n + (c5*2/15)*n    + c6*(n*8/15)
= c1*n + c2*n + (c3/3)*n + (c4*2/3)*n + (c5*2/15)*n    + (c6*8/15)*n

   /             1         2             2                8    \
= ( c1  + c2   + - c3    + - c4       + -- c5          + -- c6  ) * n
   \             3         3            15               15    /
```

All those values inside parentheses are in fact constants (since they're multiples of constants) so the whole thing is a constant multiplier of `n`.

Now, if you find a minor mistake in those equations above, I wouldn't be *too* surprised - I haven't done this level of math for quite a few years, and I may well have thrown in a furphy in case this is for homework and you try copying it verbatim :-)

But the only mistake you're likely to find is the *value* of the constant multiplier itself. It will still be a *constant* multiplier of some description, I'll guarantee that.

Comment: Can you break down the cost for the if-else statement? Like put it in algebraic terms?

Comment: @MNRC, in complexity analysis, it's irrelevant. The cost of that loop body for a single iteration is effectively constant and has no bearing on the complexity.

Comment: @paxdiablo I just added a photo of the algebraic breakdown of Insertion sort.

Comment: Yes, I can see that and, if you want that "bizarro homework" level of detail, you can certainly work it out. But you'll end up at the same O(n) figure I gave you :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Great breakdown! Thanks!! The part that had me stumped was the if-else statement because my textbook didn't include how that would be calculated. But I see now that no matter if is true or not the statement will always run *n* times.